# prepareforSegue tableViewCell to different detailTableViews

Tags: iphone, master-detail, uitableview

I´m having a tableView in a viewController with an array (3 labelTitles to 3 different detailViews). My problem is in the prepareForSegue-method, I dont really know how to call the detailViews. I use the correct segue identifiers names.

"master".m:

```
#import "GuideTableViewController.h"
#import "GuideDetailTableViewController.h"
#import "GuideDetailTableViewController2.h"
#import "GuideDetailTableViewController3.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "customImageCell.h"

@interface GuideTableViewController (){
    NSMutableData *weatherResponseData;
    NSArray *titleLabels;
    NSArray *imagesLeft;

}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgHeader;


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *ImgTitle;


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *ImgWeather;


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnMap;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *LabelWeather;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *LabelWeather2;

@end

@implementation GuideTableViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


//Weather method

- (void) loadWeather{

NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                            [NSURL    URLWithString:@"http://api.wunderground.com/api/3919480da5014c98/conditions/q/BR/Sao_Sebastiao.json"]];
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc]
                            initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
if(theConnection){
    weatherResponseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
} else {
    NSLog(@"failed");
}
}


//Delegates for WeatherData

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse  *)response
{
    [weatherResponseData setLength:0];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [weatherResponseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Failed: %@", [error description]];
    NSLog(@"%@",msg);
}

//All the data was loaded, let's see what we've got...
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSError *myError = nil;
    NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:weatherResponseData   options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves  error:&myError];
    NSArray *results =  [res objectForKey:@"current_observation"];
    NSString *cur = [results valueForKey:@"weather"];
    NSString *tmp = [results valueForKey:@"temperature_string"];
    NSString *wind = [results valueForKey:@"wind_string"];


    NSLog(@"Current conditions: %@, %@º, %@", cur, tmp, wind);


    self.LabelWeather.text = cur;

    self.LabelWeather2.text = tmp;



}







- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    [self loadWeather];


    titleLabels = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Where to stay",@"Where to eat",@"What to  do",nil];

    imagesLeft = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"btn_Stay.png", @"btn_Eat.png", @"btn_Todo.png", nil];



    //set background
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.jpg"]];

    //rounded corners

    [self.tableView.layer setCornerRadius:9.0];

    [self.ImgWeather.layer setCornerRadius:9.0];






}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


//TableView
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return titleLabels.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath {

  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

  customImageCell *cell = (customImageCell*)[tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    NSString *cellLabel = [titleLabels objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.titleLabel.text = cellLabel;

    NSString *cellImage = [imagesLeft objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImage *cellIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:cellImage];

    cell.imageLeft.image = cellIcon;


    return cell;

}

//To detailTableViewController


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath{
    if(indexPath.row == 0){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"stay" sender:self];
    }else if(indexPath.row ==1 ){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"eat" sender:self];
    }else{
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"todo" sender:self];
    }

}





- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow];

    [cell setSelected:NO];


    //Hide navbar
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
}


//Show navbar in detailView
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];   
}






@end
```

Answer (score 0):

change didselectRow

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath{
   if(indexPath.row == 0){
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"stay" sender:self];
}else if(indexPath.row ==1 ){
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"eat" sender:self];
}else{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"todo" sender:self];
}
}
```

Comment: One more thing. The "prepareForSegue"method. What should be in there?

Comment: "prepareForSegue"method is needed only if you need to set any data member of destination view  controller (pass value to destination  view controller). If you dont need this , you can omit "prepareForSegue"method.

Comment: Its still not pushing to detailview! Getting crazy! hehe I put the whole master.m for you to see now.

Comment: check storyboard and confirm Segue Name is Correct